Puppeteer and Ghostscript to minimise PDF size
I currently have a puppeteer script set up to create a PDF from an HTML file using the following code:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: [   '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
                '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
                '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
                '--disable-background-networking',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
                '--disable-breakpad',
                '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
                '--disable-component-update',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--disable-domain-reliability',
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
                '--disable-hang-monitor',
                '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
                '--disable-notifications',
                '--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-print-preview',
                '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-speech-api',
                '--disable-sync',
                '--hide-scrollbars',
                '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
                '--metrics-recording-only',
                '--mute-audio',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--no-first-run',
                '--no-pings',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--no-zygote',
                '--password-store=basic',
                '--use-gl=swiftshader',
                '--use-mock-keychain'
            ]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    var data = await fsPromises.readFile('merge.html','utf8');
                
    await page.setContent(data, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        path: 'merge.pdf',
        margin: { top: '0', right: '0', bottom: '0', left: '0' },
        printBackground: true,
        preferCSSPageSize: true
    });

    await browser.close();
})();

Once the PDF is created I then use a separate Ghostscript file executed using Coldfusion to reduce the file size:
<cfexecute name="gswin64.exe" arguments="-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=merged2.pdf merged.pdf">

But I was wondering if Ghostscript can be incorporated into the puppeteer script to have less calls and group everything together. Is that possible?

@KJ  You can call ghostscript from within puppeteer but I'm not sure of the correct syntax. The reason to get everything to work together is that I can't be 100% sure puppetter is finished before ghostscript runs and compresses the pdf. Also, what should the current syntax be for ghostscript if I am using an older version?
